# What type of verb is EAT:FEED, KNOW:INFORM

Tags: grammar, etymology, verbs, terminology, causative-verbs

We have verbs like :

**EAT > FEED**

**KNOW > INFORM**

My question is what kind of verbs are they? What are they called in grammar (e.g. causative, factitive etc)? I knew the name a long ago but forgot the exact "grammatical term" for these verbs. Where can I get a list of such verbs?

Answer (score 11):

They are verb pairs with a causative relationship. For example, the transitive verb *to feed* is the causative counterpart of *to eat*. It is more specifically a **lexical causative**. The lexical causative type involves suppletion. There is no formal similarity between the basic verb and the causative counterpart, and they generally have separate etymological paths. *To feed* can be called a causal verb and *to eat* can be called a plain verb also in this relationship.

In English, there are also analytical (periphrastic) causatives where the causation and the effect are condensed into a clause (*make him do, cause her to do*) and morphological causatives where the causative is formed with affixation or inflection. (*modern -> modernize, strength -> strengthen*)

Sometimes, this causative relationship gets more complex as there can be both intransitive and transitive senses of a verb which is called an *ambitransitive verb* or the new sense can develop over time like in the case of *to rise* and its causative counterpart *to raise*. *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/166288?rskey=rPGn96&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)* has this note in the etymology of *rise*:

> Historically rise *v.* is an intransitive verb (as likewise i-rise *v.*, arise *v.*, etc.), its causative counterparts being rear *v.1* and the Scandinavian borrowing raise *v.1* However, transitive use of rise *v.* is found in a number of senses from the 14th and 15th centuries onwards (and compare also sense 3b for earlier reflexive use). It is likely that association with the senses of raise *v.1* has exerted a considerable influence on the complex sense development of rise *v.*, and vice versa.

---

<sub>Further reading: 

Khachatryan, Robert. (2009). Ways of Expressing Causation in Modern English. Armenian Folia Anglistika. 5. 125-133. 10.46991/AFA/2009.5.1-2.125.  

[researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348919873_Ways_of_Expressing_Causation_in_Modern_English/citation/download)</sub>

Comment: Right. "Causative" is the appropriate term. It refers to a type of construction (there are several in English) and also to particular verbs, like _kill_, which always have a causative sense. Causative is paired with _inchoative_, like _die_, which have sense of `change of state`, where causatives have the sense of `cause change of state`. Statives like _dead_, of course, are just `state`.

Comment: Thank u very much, so is it Causative or lexical causative? Should I say that "feed" is the lexical causative of "eat" ?

Comment: You can use both. Lexical causative is more specific. You can say "_feed_ is a lexical causative of _eat_".

Comment: Yeah, "lexical" modifying anything just means "one-word". So _can_ is a lexical modal, but not a modal phrase like _be able to_. Likewise, "lexical semantics" means studying the meanings of words, not sentences.